# MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser Server did not publish

Tags: ios, swift, networking, multipeer-connectivity

I created a Swift project using the `Multipeer Connectivity` class. I used `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser`.

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class TestMutilpeer: NSObject {
    
    var SERVICE_NAME  = "probonjore-tcp"
    var ACK_SERVICE_NAME = "abc-txtchat"
    
    var peer: MCPeerID!
    var session: MCSession!
    var serviceAdvertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        let peer = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
        
        session = MCSession(peer: peer)
        
        let serviceAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peer, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: ACK_SERVICE_NAME)
        serviceAdvertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()
    }
}
```

And the corresponding permission is added in the info
([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIqOq.png))

But it still reports an error：

```
[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser] Server did not publish: errorDict [{
    NSNetServicesErrorCode = "-72008";
    NSNetServicesErrorDomain = 10;
}].
```

Comment: you should show a minimal reproducible example or at least some reasonable relevant code, see info here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Then, show us on which line of your code you get the error.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the service name in your plist file to `_abc-txtchat._tcp`. The value in the plist file has to conform to the Bonjour naming convention while you should continue using `abc-txtchat` while constructing `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser`.